# Want to check a constraint in the trigger to log a customized message in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a BEFORE TRIGGER on a table for INSERT and UPDATE. I am dynamically creating the code of this trigger which includes the condition of a check constraint , like,

```
if colA = 1 then colB must be 0 and colC must be 1
```

In case of insert, I check the :NEW values for all 3 columns, no issues. But in case of update how this condition should look like? User can either update one or two or all of these 3 columns. So how should I use :NEW or :OLD in case of UPDATE operation.

Looking for some pointers. Please let me know if any further information is needed.

Regards,
Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to enforce the state of the final values. So you should use `:NEW` for both inserts and updates.

```
if :new.colA = 1 
    and (:new.colB != 0 or :new.colC != 1 )
then
    -- or whatever you want to happen ....
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'your message here');
end if;
```

Alternatively you should consider using a CHECK constraint on the table. Constraints are more efficient than triggers, and are the industry standard approach for enforcing business rules like this.

```
SQL> alter table t23 add constraint t23ck 
  2      check ((cola=1 and colb=0 and colc=1)
  3              or cola != 1)
  4  /

Table altered.

SQL> insert into t23 (cola, colb, colc) values (1, 0 , 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t23 (cola, colb, colc) values (1, 0 , 2);
insert into t23 (cola, colb, colc) values (1, 0 , 2)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (FOX.T23CK) violated


SQL> insert into t23 (cola, colb, colc) values (0, 0 , 2);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

> "If user provides value only for one column so :NEW for other columns will not have anything . so I will need the existing values(:OLD) for condition check."

Fnord. The :NEW value means the *new version of the record*, not the changed values. It's quite easy to examine this behaviour with a simple test:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger t23_upd_trg
  2  before update on t23 for each row
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line ('new colA ='||:new.colA);
  5    dbms_output.put_line ('new colB ='||:new.colB);
  6    dbms_output.put_line ('new colC ='||:new.colC);
  7  end;
  8  /

  Trigger created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> select * from t23
  2  where cola = 9
  3  /

      COLA       COLB       COLC
---------- ---------- ----------
         9          4          4

SQL> update t23
  2  set cola = 1
  3  where cola = 9
  4  /
new colA =1
new colB =4
new colC =4
update t23
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (FOX.T23CK) violated
```

See? `:NEW.colb` and `:NEW.colc` return the original values because they are remain current.

> " If :OLD value is explicitly provided in the checking condition , then the :NEW will still be the new version of the record in case no value is provided for that column by the user? "

`:old` and `:new` are namespaces for referencing the different versions of the record. The `:new` value is what will be persisted to the table at the end of the transaction. If the update statement doesn't SET a column value then `:new.whatever = :old.whatever`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am indeed using a constraint. when the trigger code is generated (through a code builder logic) the constraint check becomes part of trigger logic. So If constraint breaks, I have to make an entry in log table (in trigger itself) .

Comment: Hi, One question on your resolution. If user provides value only for one column so :NEW for other columns will not have anything . so I will need the existing values(:OLD) for condition check. How to handle this scenario?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Just one more question. If :OLD value is explicitly provided in the checking condition , then the :NEW will still be the new version of the record in case no value is provided for that column by the user?